# Passing custom props to a react component using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am pretty new to TypeScript and I am wondering if someone can give me an example of this React component converted to TypeScript:

```
const Message = ({from, text}) => (
  <div>
    <p>{text}</p>
    <p>from: {from}</p>
  </div>  
);
```

I have tried somethinig like this:

```
const Message: React.FC = ({from, text}) => (
  <div>
    <p>{text}</p>
    <p>from: {from}</p>
  </div>  
);
```

but it gives me the error: Property 'propertyName' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface Props {
  from: string;
  to: string;
}

const Message: React.FC<Props> = ({from, text}) => (
  <div>
    <p>{text}</p>
    <p>from: {from}</p>
  </div>  
);
```

You just need to let Typescript know what the props for the component are.